# How to extract data from json response made by an api in python, Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

I am creating a charge and I want from it to take its 'hosted_url' in order to redirect a user from page.

I am trying to extract it from json, but I newbie and don't know how

```
        ...
        url = "https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges"

        payload = {
            "local_price": {
                "amount": 1,
                "currency": USDT
            },
            "name": "Test for fun",
            "description": "Project 2",
            "pricing_type": "fixed_price"
        }
        headers = {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "X-CC-Version": "2018-03-22",
            "X-CC-Api-Key" : "**********",
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }

        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

        print(response.text)
```

This is a code to make a request to an api in order to create a charge and in JSON Response I get these fields:

```
{
   "data":{
       "code": "123DVAS",
       "hosted_url": "https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/123DVAS",
       ...
   }
}
```

I want somehow to put this message '123DVAS' in variable or to make a redirect like this:

```
return render(request, 'https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/123DVAS')
```

Comment: Assuming response.text is actually json, you need to use json.loads ...
import json
d=json.loads(response.text)

d would be a dictionary, and d['hosted_url'] should contain the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
# Suppose it's your response looks like this
response = {"hosted_url": "https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/123DVAS"}
id_fecthed = response.get('hosted_url').split('/')[-1]

# You can redner like this
render(request, f'https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/{id_fecthed}')

# If you sure that always you want to redirect to hosted_url
# Then you can use this
render(request, response.get('hosted_url'))
```

### Edit:

Full code with data read from requests.

```
import json

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
hosted_url = data.get("data",{}).get('hosted_url')
if hosted_url:
    id_fecthed = hosted_url.split('/')[-1]
    return redirect(f'https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/{id_fecthed}')
else:
    print('Host URL not available')
```

Comment: I have an error: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I did it and appeard an error, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'. How I understood it means that string is empty but when I print(response.text) it is not empty

Comment: @Fors1t The data should available in `response.json()`. Anyways I updated the answer.

Comment: I know why hosted_url is empty, it's because my JSON Response is "data" and inside of it, is my information that I need, it is like this:
"data" : { 
"hoster_url": "https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/123DVAS"
}

Comment: @Fors1t This is the issue if you provide half-baked information in the question. Please update the question as well with all the necessary information. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question, now it's  just like in my response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248592/discussion-between-rahul-k-p-and-fors1t).